# Add if and else condition in subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

is there any way to apply if condition in subscribe function?

```
this.Subscription1 = interval(1000).subscribe(x =>
  this.seconds -= 1
);
```

such that:

```
this.Subscription1 = interval(1000).subscribe(x =>
if(this.seconds!=0){
      this.seconds -= 1
});
```

Comment: Is it Angular or AngularJS ? Please change tags accordingly.

Comment: when you want to write a multi-line statement in `subscribe`, you should start a new code block with `{ }` braces. your code lacks braces. "{}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Subscription1 = interval(1000).subscribe((x) =>
{
    if(this.seconds!=0){
          this.seconds -= 1
    }
});
```

Comment: It has the if statement wrapped in a pair of {} to turn it into a multiline function

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you just do it inside the body of the subscription.

```
this.Subscription1 = interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
  if(this.seconds != 0) {
    this.seconds -= 1
  }
});
```

### Alternative 1

You can recreate this functionality inside a pipe too.

Good for if `this.seconds` can ever go back above 0 and you want your subscription to continue receiving values.

```
this.Subscription1 = interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    // do not continue if this.seconds <= 0
    filter(() => this.seconds > 0)
    tap(() => this.seconds -= 1)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    // will only receive values if this.seconds > 0
    console.log(this.seconds);
  });
```

### Alternative 2

And if you want to close the subscription once `this.seconds` reaches 0, use `takeUntil`. There is now (probably) no need to store a reference to the subscription.

```
interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    // stop the subscription once this.seconds reaches 0
    takeUntil(() => this.seconds === 0)
    tap(() => this.seconds -= 1)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    // will only receive values if this.seconds > 0
    // won't receive values if this.seconds goes back above 0 after reaching 0
    console.log(this.seconds);
  });
```

#### Bonus tip

Use `timer(0, 1000)` if you want your subscription to fire immediately