# "If" condition within Subscribe - Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to add a toastr notification within my errorNotification function so that it would show a message if the input the user has provided is invalid. I have created customised statuses and messages in the API that I would like to display in the content of the toastr.

Is there a way I can do an "if" statement within my function such that I can do something like this:

```
async errorNotification(task: Task) {
    this.taskService
      .addTask(task)
      .subscribe((response) =>
        if (response.body.data.result === 'fail') {
          this.toastr.error(response.body.data.message)
        }
        else {
          this.toastr.success(response.body.data.message)
        }
      );
  }
```

This is my current code:

```
async errorNotification(task: Task) {
    this.taskService
      .addTask(task)
      .subscribe((response) =>
        console.log(response.body.data.result, response.body.data.message)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Usually, you will get the error as a 2nd arg of the subscribe. Can you try something like : `subscribe((response) => this.toastr.success(...), (error)=> this.toastr.error(...))`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I think I cant do error because some of the responses may be 200 but as the data.result for them is a "fail", I want it to be flagged as an error as well

Comment: You could enclose the `subscribe` callback in braces `{}`: `.subscribe((response) => { /* do something */ }`.

Comment: `.subscribe()` should not have code in it. use `.pipe(catchError(), tap())`, in the catch Error you will have code that shows toastr according to the error you receive.

Comment: @Shraga Yes, I thik that is a better way and I saw a post previously on this which was describing how it is used with interceptors, but Im not sure how to relate that to this.
 https://itnext.io/handle-http-responses-with-httpinterceptor-and-toastr-in-angular-3e056759cb16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to wait for the response of addTask? Instead of treating the error right there?

```
addTask(task: Task): Observable<any> {
  return someAsyncCall(task).pipe(
     tap((response) => 
       response.body.data.result === 'fail'
        ? this.toastr.error(response.body.data.message)
        : this.toastr.success(response.body.data.message)
      )
  );
}
```

And with this approach you don't need an aditional function

Answer (score 0):

You can do the check you need inside the body of the subscription, with braces {} like this :

```
.subscribe((response) =>
// Add next line
{
    if (response.body.data.result === 'fail') {
      this.toastr.error(response.body.data.message)
    }
    else {
      this.toastr.success(response.body.data.message)
    }
// Add next line
  }
  );
```

[You could find more informations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372419/add-if-and-else-condition-in-subscribe-in-angular)

I prefer to use await for clarity purpose :

```
const response = await this.taskService.addTask(task);
if (response.body.data.result === 'fail') {
   this.toastr.error(response.body.data.message);
} else {
   this.toastr.success(response.body.data.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I get an error that says "Module parse failed: The keyword 'yield' is reserved (392:20)"

Comment: Mmh, did you also try :
this.taskService.addTask(task).subscribe((response) => { /* do something */ })

with {} around what follow ".subscribe((response) =>"

Comment: would you be able to write it out please, I dont think I can follow you @Bruno Hanss